# Finding a certain set of numbers from a list

Tags: algorithm, list, set

I am working on this project where the user inputs a list of numbers. I put these numbers in an array. I need to find a set of numbers with a given length whose sum is divisible by 5.

For example, if the list is 9768014, and the length required is 6, then the output would be 987641.

What algorithm do I need to find that set of numbers?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I tried something simple, but it didn't work. I am trying an algorithm where I get the maximum sum, and if that isn't the answer, then I replace the smallest number with the next smallest number. However, this gets complicated when the actual answer requires changing the not smallest digit.

Comment: Can you post your code for the original algorithm?

Comment: It's really better to present your code (at least the most related parts of it) so that we can understand what you really need and help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by dynamic programming. Let f(n,m,k) be the largest index between 1 and n of the number in a subset of indices {1,2,....,n} that gives a sum of k mod 5 that uses m numbers. (It's possible that f(n,m,k) = None). You can compute f(n+1,m,k) and f(n,m+1,k) if you know the values of f(N,M,k) for all N <= n + 1 and M < m and also for all N <= n and M < m + 1 and also for N=n,M=m, and all k = 0,1,2,3,4. If you ever find that f(n,m,0) has a solution where m is your desired number of numbers to use, then you're done. Also you don't have to compute f(N,M,k) for any M greater than your desired count of numbers to use. Total complexity is O(n*m) where n is the total count of numbers and m is the size of subset that you are trying to reach.

Comment: Could you elaborate some more? I'm sorry, I don't quite see what you are trying to do. Could you use pseudocode to elaborate?

Comment: Sure, I'll add to my answer.

Comment: Could you make some pseudocode? I see what you are telling me, but I don't know how I would put that into actual code.